# How to use temporary AWS keys instead of env variables with the Java AWS SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using `saml2aws` to generate temporary AWS keys for my clients. Previously I was using environmental variables:

```
aws_access_key_id=MY KEY
aws_secret_access_key=MY SECRET
```

After authenticating with `saml2aws` my `~/.aws/config` file looks like this *(unchanged)*:

```
[default]
output=json
```

And my `~/.aws/credentials` looks like this:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id        = MY KEY ID
aws_secret_access_key    = MY KEY
aws_session_token        = MY SESSION TOKEN
aws_security_token       = MY TOKEN
x_principal_arn          = MY ARN
x_security_token_expires = TIME
```

When I try this from the cli with `aws s3 ls` it works but when I try to access S3 from the Java SDK:

```
AmazonS3Client(ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                .listObjects(ListObjectsRequest()
                        .withBucketName("some-bucket")
                        .withPrefix("some-prefix")
                        .withDelimiter("/")
                        .withMaxKeys(10000))
```

I get:

> com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load credentials into profile. Profile Name or AWS Access Key ID or AWS Secret Access Key missing for a profile.

And it doesn't work even if I explicitly try to use the `default` profile: `ProfileCredentialsProvider("default")` or even if I don't set a provider at all!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked that java is using your user and home folder?

Comment: That's not the case. If I tamper with the file I get different exceptions. I'm not sure how to configure the client itself. I think the problem comes from there.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason setting the credentials on the default AWS profile using saml2aws does return an error, but creating a new profile works just fine, so here are the steps I followed:

1. Specify a profile when logging in through saml2aws e.g. `saml2aws login --profile prod`
2. Specify `prod` profile using the SDK or through an environment variable `set AWS_PROFILE="prod"`

Answer (score 0):

```
AmazonS3Client().listObjects(ListObjectsRequest()
                        .withBucketName("some-bucket")
                        .withPrefix("some-prefix")
                        .withDelimiter("/")
                        .withMaxKeys(10000))
```

is enough, no need of explicitly giving `ProfileCredentialsProvider()`.
For more see

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#AmazonS3Client--

Comment: can you try by setting the profile `set AWS_PROFILE="default"`